# TFS 2017 User Group Created and Need mail notification when the User group User Added\delete modified

Tags: tfs

Example:

UserGroup 1:
 1) User1
 2) User2
 3) User3

Now when a User2 is removed from the UserGroup1 need a email notification when existing user removed\added from the Group.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we cannot achieve that, there isn't the feature for now, the alert is not applied to add/remove user/group. See [Set alerts, get notified when changes occur](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/track/alerts-and-notifications) for details.

We can only receive email notifications for alerts that you define as changes occur to work items, code reviews, source control files, and builds.

However that makes sense, I have submitted a [**user voice here**](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/20574703-tfs-team-member-receive-email-notification-when-an) to suggest this feature, you can go and vote it up to achieve it in future.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.